# React Redux with multi applyMiddleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I want to use the following answer
[Redux state persistence with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726644/redux-state-persistence-with-a-database)

```
import {createStore, compose, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';

const localStorageMiddleware = ({getState}) => {
  return (next) => (action) => {
    const result = next(action);
    localStorage.setItem('applicationState', JSON.stringify(
      getState()
    ));
    return result;
  };
};

const store = compose(
  applyMiddleware(
    localStorageMiddleware
  )
)(createStore)(
  reducer,
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('applicationState'))
)
```

But I didn't understand the javascript syntax here
How he used `compose(argument)(createStore)(argument)`?

is there any alternative like `createStore(reducer,initialState,compose(argument))`?

Also, how is initial state will be passed here

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(  
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {  
  const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer);
  return store;
}
```

Comment: compose returns a function which has the same signature as the first argument - createStore, then that function is invoked with the second arguments. - reducer and the initial state

Comment: @ReiDien is there any tutorial about this syntax in javascript?

Comment: i dont have any. maybe just deep understanding on function can help you resolve the complication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!  The `enhancer()(createStore)` syntax is the older-style way of using `createStore`, and we are trying to encourage people to use the newer syntax instead:

```
const composedEnhancers = compose(
    firstEnhancer,
    secondEnhancer
);

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    preloadedState,
    composedEnhancers
);
```

Comment: do you know any source for javascript function like func1(arg)func2(arg) ?

Comment: That's a Functional Programming approach called "currying", or perhaps just a function returning another function. I have links to some [articles on Functional Programming concepts](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/functional-programming.md) that might be useful.